# Why Backtrader doesn't show xticks when plotting graph?

Tags: plot, xticks, backtrader

it's weird my backtrader doesn't show xticks on most of my testing cases when i use cerebro.plot(style='candlestick'), I check it out on internet and find out it's not just me. Can anybody help us out there? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to backtrader\plot\plot.py...find the line and change visible to True:

```
for ax in laxis:
    self.mpyplot.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
```